# What is a good substitute that is less localized than "secular"?

Tags: synonyms

I am having trouble using the term "secular" to convey a sense of bringing a religiously neutral ground to government, society, and culture. What term is better than "secular", that is less localized than the US-connotative sense, but conveys the same general meaning to multiple  countries?

Secularism is often denoted the same, but from country to country it is practiced on a sliding scale in terms of how truly neutral laws are. [Some of us on the Atheism.se are trying to broaden the scope of the site and are interested in methods for doing this](http://meta.atheism.stackexchange.com/q/261/135). The usage of "secular" (that I am looking for) should convey taking secularism and using it as a tool for atheist questions to hone in on issues regarding equal rights, activism, promotion.

Comment: Are you looking for a word that is devoid of any reference to religion? If so, *secular* is about as good as you will do. Other words like *temporal* or *earthly* generally validate a belief in a spiritual realm by implying that such a thing exists.

Comment: I still don't really see the problem: "secular" seems to be exactly right. Is there a specific sentence you need this word in?

Comment: @Cer let me know if the edit helps

Comment: Ditto above.  Only alternative coming to mind is Temporal here, which would likely get downvoted for carrying too strong a religious connotation for atheism.

Comment: Okay, I have read your link. I do not see a very specific reference to "secular" there, so I assume that you intend to broaden the scope of the Atheism website to include secularisation and secularism. In that context, "secular", "secularisation", and "secularism" seem to be the perfect words. In Dutch, "secularisation" would be the taking-away of property from the Church, but I have absolutely no problem reading it in a somewhat different sense in English.

Comment: @Cer sorry, secularism was one idea (in an answer) to broaden the scope of Atheism without dragging another discipline into it. In chat though it was causing issues with having a spot-on meaning

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Secular is perfect as far as I can see. It carries no 'local' connotations. You might perhaps use 'humanist'.

Comment: This is for the atheism site, and humanism carries with it moral/ethical baggage it likely wouldn't carry generally. Secular has a usage problem; ie one of our users is Russian and that word just isn't used. On the flip side, if you look at Greece's anti-proselytizing laws, it goes tolerance of views one further and limits freedom of speech (IMO) making proselytizing illegal in some cases.

Comment: Well, why not use your own phrase of 'religiously neutral'?

Comment: @mfg: Not to sound snarky, but point that user to a dictionary. Or to the Russian Wikipedia, which has entries on [secularism](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC), [secular humanism](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC), [secularization](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F_%28%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), and whatnot.

Comment: @Reg Remember that secularism is on a sliding scale. I use those two examples, but I could substitute Ireland & India and it is equally applicable; in neither case would the user / site visitor have a precise idea of what secular entails.

Comment: @RegDwight I am that user. Thank you very much for pointing me to the Russian Wikipedia, but I've made sure I've visited it before claiming that the word is not used. A few experts might use it in technical conversations, which doesn't entail the word being in common usage. As long as the word is not common enough outside of the US (and perhaps English-speaking countries), it wouldn't make a very good descriptive word for an international StackExchange for atheists in general. “What, you don't know what [Marxist revisionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revisionism_(Marxism)) means?”

Comment: @mfg: Language related to religion (or lack thereof :) is a minefield. I think if you're looking for a word which (a) has a very precise meaning that you want to convey, (b) is understood by multinational readers whose native language may not be English, and (c) you want them all to understand exactly the same meaning, that's asking a lot! You may be best either using a longer phrase, or using a word such as secular (or an alternative such as "nonreligious", "civic", or perhaps "lay" though that has the problem that Robusto noted in his comment...), but very carefully defining it on your site.

Comment: Is the language of atheism.se not English?  If it *is* English, I really do not see the problem; or the problem is indeed localized... local to the user, that is.  (And if Ireland is relevant: could you point me/us somewhere with an explanation of the Irish' problem?)

Comment: @Vitaly: I'm not sure I am following. If that site were in Russian, I might think twice before using *секулярный*. However, as long as the international StackExchange is in English, it is perfectly fine to use the English word *secular*. In my humble opinion, as a native speaker of Russian, I don't get to decide which words native speakers of English must or must not use in their conversation, even — no, make that *especially* — if I wish to participate in that conversation.

Comment: @jae Sorry, but are you sure you are not mixing up English (as the language) and concepts local to the US (as an English speaking country)? [Marxism-Leninism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marxism–Leninism) *is* an English phrase, but how many native English speakers would have a precise idea of what the phrase entails? The problem is that the *concept*, to which the word ‘secularism’ refers in English, is localized.

Comment: @mgf: fair to say, but the same is true of a great many other words, from *atheism* to *god* to *humanism* to *proselytizing*. (I'm kind of echoing psmears here.) Not every user/visitor will have a precise idea what these words mean to you, either.

Comment: @Vitaly no, it's not, the only person here claiming it is is you; if you have *evidence*, then please let me/us know (that's what the bit about Ireland is about).

Comment: @Reg true, and we are trying to tamp down loose usage as often our comment sections end up looking like *intestines with diverticulitis*. If secular is as good as it gets, so be it; it may have been a weak choice on my part considering the purpose.

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a term to convey the opposite of superstition, the broader process of organising society according to non-superstitious principles, you might use "rationalisation" and "rational", or perhaps "evidence-based", "empiricism", and "science". But you've probably already considered those terms.

Comment: +1 I think if for some reason the word "secular" is insufficient, then emphasising the fact-based approach rather than faith-based is entirely correct.

Comment: @Orbling: Exactly my thinking, though I am not yet sure I got what Mfg is looking for exactly. It can be so difficult to communicate thoughts.

Comment: +1 for rational or rationality.